# Where can I get bluez-utils for 17.10?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

Commands like `sudo bt-device -s 00:00:00:00:00:00` result in the following:

> Discovering services... Failed to start SDP discovery. Please make sure you have bluez-utils installed on your system.

Yet there doesn't seem to be, or have been for a while, a `bluez-utils` package.

What should I be using to determine the services/capabilities/functions of bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 1):

#### Installing bluez-utils

Recently, `bluez-utils` has been replaced by `bluez`... With this being said, to simply install it, you should be able to run something like:

```
sudo apt udpate && sudo apt install bluez
```

Best of wishes!

Comment: It is very much installed. Anything else that could be causing this (misleadingly annotated) error?